# angular material select options are displaying top of the page

Tags: angular-material

I am using angular material version 1.1.1 and angularjs version 1.5.5. But the selected options are displaying top of the page.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
       <span>What is your favorite weapon?</span>
       <md-select ng-model="weapon" placeholder="Weapon" class="md-no-underline">
          <md-option value="axe">Axe</md-option>
          <md-option value="sword">Sword</md-option>
          <md-option value="wand">Wand</md-option>
          <md-option value="pen">Pen?</md-option>
       </md-select>
</div>
```

Is there any fix for this issue?

Please find the following screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Seems okay - https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/gwpPAN?editors=1010#0. Do you have any other CSS that is affecting it?

Comment: Actually i have a sidebar having height 100%. If i remove the height is is working. but i need body height 100%.                                              body,
body > div {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body > div {
    height: 100%;
}